# Connecting One Office 365 Email Account to another using Connected Accounts using IMAP

Tags: email, outlook, office365, imap

My client is trying to connect one Office 365 Email account to another using "Connecting Accounts" in Outlook for the Web using IMAP. When doing this, it fails with an error that it can't connect to the account. The account cannot be connected via the "insecure" method, nor does it work when you manually type in the IMAP settings. The Office 365 email accounts are on separate Office 365 accounts, but I suspect this also occurs when they are on the same Office 365 account as well.

*I'm posting this as a question, and then answering my own question in an effort to help someone else with the same problem.*

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Microsoft Outlook for the Web. You can workaround it by manually creating the "connected accounts" using Powershell.

Run Powershell as an administrator by making a right click on Powershell.

You can connect Powershell to Exchange Online using the below commands one by one:

```
set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned

$LiveCred = Get-Credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session
```

Then execute the below command:

```
New-ImapSubscription -Name "Connected account" -Mailbox "Email address of the target mailbox" -EmailAddress "Email address of the source mailbox" -IncomingUserName "Email address of the source mailbox" -IncomingPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password of the source mailbox' -AsPlainText -Force) -IncomingServer Outlook.office365.com -IncomingSecurity Ssl -IncomingPort 993
```

So below are the string that you need to replace with values:
Email address of the target mailbox
Email address of the source mailbox
Password of the source mailbox